# Why would crypt() return an asterisk?

Tags: php, crypt

I am building a login system using PHP and `crypt()`.  The first time I ran it, `crypt('some_password')` returned a `*` (asterisk).  I ran the script a few more times, but I could not get crypt to return another asterisk.  What would cause this behavior?

The only record that I had of this result was stored directly in my database via Codeigniter.  the password field contained a single asterisk and nothing else.

Database insert code:

```
$this->CI->db->query( ... VALUES ("'.$username.'", "'.$password.'",  ...
```

Comment: `*` is an encrypted password, this is why passwords are made of plenty of little asterisks.

Comment: @presiuslitelsnoflek that's not true. `*` is not an encrypted password, but it commonly used by user interfaces to represent a character in a password.

Comment: Are you sure it was `*`, and not `"*0"` or `"*1"`?

Comment: Darn!  I thought my ***** root password was original and secure.  Now I need to change all of my passwords.

Comment: * was the only character stored in the database (I doubt that the 0 or 1 could be lost along the way, but stranger things have been known to happen.)

Comment: If PHP version < 5.3.2, crypt *might* have returned `*0` or `*1` when blowfish fails. ref: http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.crypt.php

Comment: What could cause blowfish to fail?